# Using dependencies of some dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a *project-test* which contains all classes that are used in JUnit Tests of others projects (e.g builders tests). In pom.xml of project-test I added Mockito and Junit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Note that many projects needs to use project-test to import JUnit and Mockito dependency. *Foo project* has a pom.xml with project-test dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <!-- <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <!-- Nexus config -->
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It needs to import some packages like:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
```

I executed *mvn clean install* and the .jar inside */home/danielamorais/.m2/repository/br/com/company/project-test/1.0-SNAPSHOT* exists. Why I can't import Junit and Mockito in my Foo Project?

> Error:(8, 17) java: package org.junit does not exist

Comment: Because they're test dependencies of your project-test project. So that means they're supposed to be used only to test this project, and are thus not dependencies of the classes of the project-test jar file. BTW, I wonder how you compiled those classes of project-test in the firt place, since they're supposed to depend on junit and mockito, but those are only in the test classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet. Classes of project-test doesn't import JUnit or Mockito.  Actually this classes are this builders: http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html (I think I don't describe it right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are test scope dependencies and will only be applicable when running the test.

I hope you are testing this by executing the `mvn test`.

ex `mvn -Dtest=YourTestCase test`

Answer (score 0):

Like *JB Nizet* and *Nrj* mentioned, it's a matter of *scopes*. Check [Maven documentation on the subject](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

I just wanted to add that instead of creating a whole new project for grouping your common dependencies, a simpler and common practice is to create a *parent POM* then your other POMs can inherit from it. Read more about it [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html), there are a couple [examples](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Example_1).

Answer (score 0):

As an artifact declare as dependency another artifact, dependencies with the `test` scope  are not inherited in the declaring artifact.

If what you want is defining common dependencies (and same common configuration) for multiple artifacts, use the feature designed to : the parent pom.
Define a parent pom that holds common configuration and make your two artifacts some child modules of it.
You may also make the parent pom a aggregator/multi-module pom if required.

**Parent pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**project-test (jar)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
      <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project-test</artifactId>

</project>
```

**foo (war app)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
      <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>


</project>
```